# Getting error while executing rest service

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I'm new to .Net and I'm getting following error while I execute following code. I wanted to Map my response into ESBResponse class and get the status of response.

### Error

```
One or more errors occurred. --->
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1   position 14. 
Expecting element 'ArrayOfESBResponse' 
from namespace ''.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'esbresponse', namespace ''.
```

### Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{



[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "")]
public class ESBResponse
{

    [DataMember] 
    public string status { get; set; }
}


public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {

        String url = "http://192.168.10.3:9797";
        String xml = "<apprequest><txnid>01472633956983096440</txnid><timestamp>1472633956988</timestamp><phoneno /><rokaid>BAT1234</rokaid><category>Customer</category><RequestType>App</RequestType><IMEINO>359861050082439</IMEINO><appType>IOS</appType><reqIP>192.168.13.201</reqIP></apprequest>";
        String response = postXMLData(url, xml);

        Debug.WriteLine("RESPONE ####### " + response);

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }


    public string postXMLData(string destinationUrl, string requestXml)
    {
        /**  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
          byte[] bytes;
          bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
          request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
          request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
          request.Method = "POST";
          Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
          requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
          requestStream.Close();
          HttpWebResponse response; 
          response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
         */

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(destinationUrl);

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

        var httpContent = new StringContent(requestXml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");


        var response = client.PostAsync("/RokaServices/Api/rokaidavailable", httpContent).Result;
        Debug.WriteLine("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% " + response);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            try
            {
                // your code 

            //Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<ESBResponse>>().Result;

            foreach (var d in dataObjects)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% " + d.status);
            }

            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% " + e.ToString());
            }


           //  responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
           // return responseStr;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

### Sample Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><esbresponse><txnid>01472633956983096440</txnid><RequestType>App</RequestType><IMEINO>359861050082439</IMEINO><phoneno/><rokaid>BAT1234</rokaid><category>Customer</category><otp/><isrokaidavailable>true</isrokaidavailable><status>success</status></esbresponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error would be occurred in this line :

```
 var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<ESBResponse>>().Result;
```

You wanna to cast the result to `**IEnumerable < ESBResponse >**` but your response does not contains a list of ESBResponse, your response as I see is just one instance of `ESBResponse`, Try to cast to he `ESBResponse` like this :

```
 response.Content.ReadAsAsync< ESBResponse >().Result;
```